# Bound on minimum perturbation of eigenvalues, based on condition number

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, matrix-norms, condition-number

**Problem:** This problem comes from a past Ph.D. qualifying exam at my institution.

> Let $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
> \newcommand{\l}{\lambda}
> A \in \R^{n \times n}$ be of full rank and diagonalizable as $A = XDX^{-1}$ (for $D$ a diagonal matrix, and $X \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\R)$). Let $\l_1,\cdots,\l_n$ denote the eigenvalues of $A$, and let $A':=A+E$ for some $E \in \R^{n\times n}$. Let $\l'$ be an eigenvalue of $A'$.
>
> Prove: $\displaystyle \min_{1 \le i \le n} |\l' -\l_i| \le \kappa_2(X) \cdot \|E\|_2$

---

**Relevant Definitions:** Most of these are basic stuff, but for completion's sake:

- $\mathrm{rank}(M) := \dim \mathrm{range}(M)$, and is of ***full rank*** if $M \in \R^{n \times n}$ and $\mathrm{rank}(M) = n$
- $\l$ is an ***eigenvalue*** of $M$ with eigenvector $v$ when $Mv=\l v$
- The ***$2$-norm of a matrix*** is induced from the $\ell^2$ norm:
  $$
  \|M\|_2 := \sup_{0 \ne x \in \R^n} \frac{\|Mx\|_2}{\|x\|_2} \equiv \sup_{\substack{x \in \R^n \\ \|x\|_2 = 1}} \|Mx\|_2$$
- The ***$2$-condition number*** $\kappa_2(M)$ of a matrix $M$ is defined by
  $$
  \kappa_2(M) := \|M\|_2 \cdot \|M^{-1}\|_2
  $$
  provided $M$ is invertible. More generally, if $M$ is of full rank one may use
  $$
  \kappa_2(M) := \|M\|_2 \cdot \|M^+\|_2
  $$
  where $M^+$ is the ***(Moore-Penrose) pseudoinverse***
  $$
  M^+ := (M^\ast M)^{-1} M^\ast
  $$

---

I haven't done much work with conditioning numbers and perturbations (since fundamentally that feels like what $E$ is "meant" to be). I do know of some basic results like

$$\kappa_2(M) = \frac{\max \{ \sigma \in \R \mid \sigma \text{ is a singular value of } M \}}{\min \{ \sigma \in \R \mid \sigma \text{ is a singular value of } M \}}$$

but ultimately I'm not seeing how I could retrieve *any* sort of result.

Nudges/hints in the right direction would be much appreciated; I've been doing fine on many of the problems so far, but this one has me stumped.

Comment: Simplify your life, refocus on finding the eigenvalues of $D+X^{-1}EX$.

Comment: This seems like the Bauer-Fike theorem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauer%E2%80%93Fike_theorem, and references therein.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!